# difficulty in understanding c++ function that resolves function names by ordinals

Tags: c++, winapi

I am following a malware analysis course. And I came across this code which I found confusing. The first two sections make sense but the part where the if statement starts is very difficult for me to understand. This "if" statement is supposed to resolve function names by ordinals. I have put my questions in the comments.

```
FARPROC WINAPI myGetProcAddress(HMODULE hMod, char * sProcName) {

    char * pBaseAddress = (char *) hMod;

    // get pointers to main headers/structures
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER * pDosHdr = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *) pBaseAddress;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * pNTHdr = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *) (pBaseAddress + pDosHdr->e_lfanew);
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER * pOptionalHdr = &pNTHdr->OptionalHeader;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY * pDataDir = (IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY *) (&pOptionalHdr->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT]);
    IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY * pExportDirAddr = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *) (pBaseAddress + pDataDir->VirtualAddress);

    // resolve addresses to Export Address Table, table of function names and "table of ordinals"
    DWORD * pEAT = (DWORD *) (pBaseAddress + pExportDirAddr->AddressOfFunctions);
    DWORD * pFuncNameTbl = (DWORD *) (pBaseAddress + pExportDirAddr->AddressOfNames);
    WORD * pHintsTbl = (WORD *) (pBaseAddress + pExportDirAddr->AddressOfNameOrdinals);

    // function address we're looking for
    void *pProcAddr = NULL;

    // resolve function by ordinal
    if (((DWORD_PTR)sProcName >> 16) == 0) { // why shift by 16
        WORD ordinal = (WORD) sProcName & 0xFFFF;   // why & 0xFFFF
        DWORD Base = pExportDirAddr->Base;          

        if (ordinal < Base || ordinal >= Base + pExportDirAddr->NumberOfFunctions)
            return NULL;

        // not sure what this part does
        pProcAddr = (FARPROC) (pBaseAddress + (DWORD_PTR) pEAT[ordinal - Base]);
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I would very much appreciate some explanation.

Comment: Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This allows you to split a number (here dword or double word) in two parts using bit operations, e.g:

```
0x12345678 >> 16 = 0x1234 (hi order word)
0x12345678 & 0xFFFF = 0x5678 (lo order word)
```

Why is the code doing that? It's documented with [GetProcAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress#parameters)'s lpProcName parameter:

> The function or variable name, or the function's ordinal value. If
> this parameter is an ordinal value, it must be in the low-order word;
> the high-order word must be zero.

Comment: So, the if statement only gets executed if the high order bits are zero. E.g. 0x00004444 will enter the if statement but 0x12341234 will not. Am I correct?

Comment: A note on the other question: `sProcName & 0xFFFF` isn't strictly required. `WORD ordinal = (WORD)sProcName;` would be perfectly sufficient, since the expression in the `if` statement already ensured that no bits at position 16 and above are non-zero. I'm guessing it's there for readability and to make it easier to change code; an optimizing compiler is likely to remove the redundant masking.

Comment: @Stevey - yes you are

Comment: @ste The right-shift operator isn't particularly ideal. It will produce the desired result here only because `DWORD` (and `WORD`) are unsigned. A more obvious way to express the same would be `if (((DWORD_PTR)sProcName & ~0xFFFF) == 0) { ... }`.

Comment: @IInspectable
Since I am relatively new to this, can you please explain the condition. How is it obvious? Thanks.

Comment: `~` is the "bitwise NOT" operator, that creates the bitwise mirror image of a value. Each bit that's set in the source value isn't set in the result, and vice versa. `~0xFFFF` produces a value where each bit is set except for the bottom 16 bits. A "bitwise AND" operation with that value masks out the bottom 16 bits, and leaves every bit above unchanged. The expression can be compared for equality with 0. If it compares equal, then there aren't any bits set at position 16 or above. Otherwise, at least one bit is set at position 16 or above.

Comment: The `IS_INTRESOURCE()` macro can be used to achieve the same result.